# Outlook Rest Api -- Get a calendar view (REST) in particular timezone

Tags: javascript, rest, outlook, calendar, office365

I'm trying to retrieve a calendar view in particular time zone. According to [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#get-events) we need to use the Prefer: outlook.timezone header to specify the time zone. But after setting the prefer header the api is returning 400 error status.

```
            var queryParams = {
              'startDateTime' : params.timeMin,
              'endDateTime' : params.timeMax,
              '$select': 'Start,End'
            }
            // header 
            var headers = {
              'Prefer' : 'Asia/Kolkata'
            }
            request.get({url:'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview',
                         qs:queryParams, 
                         json:true, 
                         'auth': { 'bearer': token},
                          headers: headers
                       }, function(error, response, body) {

            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change

```
var headers = {
    'Prefer' : 'Asia/Kolkata'
};
```

to

```
var headers = {
    'Prefer' : 'outlook.timezone="Asia/Kolkata"'
};
```

In case of header `'Prefer' : 'Asia/Kolkata'` server responds with *invalid Prefer header* error.

The valid format for `Prefer` header is:

```
Prefer: outlook.timezone="<time zone>"
```

**References**

[List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)